# Error running startx on CentOS via SSH

Tags: centos, ssh, gnome

Whenever I attempt to run `startx` on a system I have SSHed into, I get the following output:

```
xauth:  creating new authority file /root/.serverauth.6604


X.Org X Server 1.15.0  
Release Date: 2013-12-27  
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0  
Build Operating System: c6b8 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64  
Current Operating System: Linux ns506320.ip-192-99-5.net 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 15 04:27:16 UTC 2014 x86_64  
Kernel command line: root=/dev/md1  ro crashkernel=131M@0M SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 KEYTABLE=us  
Build Date: 10 April 2015  11:56:50AM  
Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.15.0-26.el6.centos  
Current version of pixman: 0.32.4  
        Before reporting problems, check https://www.redhat.com/apps/support/ to make sure that you have the latest version.  
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,  
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,  
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.  
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue May 19 19:50:58 2015  
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"  
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension  
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE  
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM  
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension  
Initializing built-in extension XTEST  
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS  
Initializing built-in extension SYNC  
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD  
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC  
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY  
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA  
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES  
Initializing built-in extension RENDER  
Initializing built-in extension RANDR  
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE  
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE  
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER  
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER  
Initializing built-in extension RECORD  
Initializing built-in extension DPMS  
Initializing built-in extension Present  
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource  
Initializing built-in extension XVideo  
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation  
Initializing built-in extension SELinux  
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension  
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA  
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI  
Initializing built-in extension DRI2  
Loading extension GLX  
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:  
> Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86AudioMicMute  
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server  
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:  
> Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86AudioMicMute  
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server  
GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET=/tmp/keyring-LMTkmp/socket  
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-LMTkmp/socket.ssh  
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=6657  

** (gnome-panel:6674): WARNING **: panel-applet-frame.c:1288: failed to load applet OAFIID:GnoteApplet: (null)  

** (gnome-panel:6674): CRITICAL **: panel_applet_frame_change_background:   
assertion `PANEL_IS_WIDGET (GTK_WIDGET (frame)->parent)' failed
```

[Original pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Vd5X86qC)